# I need a pattern in excel for certain columns

Tags: excel

[Pattern Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh9sx.png)

Column B: 8 times of cells in Column A

Column C: 8 sets of same cells repeting till the end of Column B

Answer (score 0):

Column B

```
=INDEX(A:A,(ROW()-1)/8+1)
```

Column C

```
=MOD(ROW()-1,8)+1
```